# Ada Error actual for "Element_Type" must be a definite subtype when Vector contains Strings

Tags: ada

My goal is to print all forms of trees with N nodes in parenthetical notation, which can be defined as follows in terms of a Context-Free Grammar:

T → tree is empty

T → (T.T) a node with left & right children

For instance, all trees with 3 nodes will look like:

(((.).).)

((.(.)).)

((.).(.))

(.((.).))

(.(.(.)))

And I've written the following code in Ada,

```
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Command_Line;
procedure Ass1 is 
     X: Positive := Positive'Value(Ada.Command_Line.Argument(1));
    package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
     (Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => String);

    function tree(N: Integer) return String_Vectors.Vector is
    Strings : String_Vectors.Vector;    
    begin
        if N = 1 then
            Strings.Append("(.)");
            return Strings;
        end if;
        for T in tree(N - 1).Iterate loop
            Strings.Append("(" & T & ".)");
            Strings.Append("(." & T & ")");
        end loop;
    return Strings;
    end tree;


begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Ass1(X));
end;
```

But I get this error:

```
ass1.adb:9:09: instantiation error at a-convec.ads:375
ass1.adb:9:09: unconstrained element type in array declaration
ass1.adb:11:27: actual for "Element_Type" must be a definite subtype
ass1.adb:21:36: invalid operand types for operator "&"
ass1.adb:22:37: invalid operand types for operator "&"
ass1.adb:29:16: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
ass1.adb:29:16: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Put_Line" declared at a-textio.ads:259
ass1.adb:29:26: expected type "Standard.String"
ass1.adb:29:26: found private type "Ada.Containers.Vectors.Vector" from instance at line 9
ass1.adb:29:26:   ==> in call to "Put_Line" at a-textio.ads:263
x86_64-linux-gnu-gnatmake-7: "ass1.adb" compilation error
```

What is a definite subtype and why is String not one? I thought & is used for string concatenation in Ada.

--------- Edit ----------
I changed my code to follows according to the answers:

```
with Ada.Containers; use Ada.Containers;
with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors;

with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;

with Ada.Command_Line;
procedure Tree is
         X: Positive := Positive'Value(Ada.Command_Line.Argument(1));
        package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors
         (Index_Type   => Natural,
          Element_Type => String);

        function Tree(N: Integer) return String_Vectors.Vector is
        Strings : String_Vectors.Vector;
        begin
            if N = 1 then
                Strings.Append("(.)");
                return Strings;
            end if;
            for T in Tree(N - 1).Iterate loop
                Strings.Append("(" & T & ".)");
                Strings.Append("(." & T & ")");
            end loop;
        return Strings;
        end Tree;


begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line(Tree(X));
end;
```

But I still get the following errors:

```
gnatmake tree.adb 6
gcc -c tree.adb
tree.adb:21:36: invalid operand types for operator "&"
tree.adb:22:37: invalid operand types for operator "&"
tree.adb:29:16: no candidate interpretations match the actuals:
tree.adb:29:16: missing argument for parameter "Item" in call to "Put_Line" declared at a-textio.ads\
:498
tree.adb:29:26: expected type "Standard.String"
tree.adb:29:26: found private type "Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors.Vector" from instance at line \
9
tree.adb:29:26:   ==> in call to "Put_Line" at a-textio.ads:508
gnatmake: "tree.adb" compilation error
```

The operand problem is still there. Put_Line according to documentation can accept one parameter so why is there a missing parameter? And I don't understand the private type "Indefinite_Vectors.Vector" error either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A definite subtype is a subtype whose size is known at compile-time. More information about it, you can find in [Ada Wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Type_System#Indefinite_subtype). Your String don't have declared length thus is an indefinite type.

Solutions:

1. If you know size of String which will be stored in Vector, you can declare it, for example:

```
    package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
     (Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => String(1 .. 20));
```

2. Use Unbounded_String instead, this will require to change your further code too (to use everywhere Unbounded_String or to cast it to String):

```
    package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
     (Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => Unbounded_String);
```

3. Use Indefinite_Vector instead of Vector:

```
    package String_Vectors is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Vectors
     (Index_Type   => Natural,
      Element_Type => String);
```

All next errors (this one with "&" too) are effect of the first problem with wrong definition of the String_Vectors).

---

**Updated to the new version of question:**

Still few things need attention here:

1. Append (lines 21 and 22) - when you want to add one type to another (in your example, strings and vector cursor), you must cast one of them to other. Thus this lines should looks that:

```
Strings.Append("(" & Natural'Image(String_Vectors.To_Index(T)) & ".)");
```

First you cast vector Cursor to Natural, then you cast it to String so you can concatenate them.

2. Put_Line (line 29) - In Ada you can't in that way print Vectors (if I good guess, this is what you want to do?) If you want to print content of the vector, you must print each of its element:

```
for Item of Tree(X) loop
   Put_Line(Item);
end loop;
```

Other errors should be again, effect of this two problems (at least everything compile for me and works).

Comment: (3) is almost certainly best. You will find more, interesting, errors after making this change!

Comment: Oh, yes, especially if you will try to add strings with different sizes :)

Comment: @thindil, the ```Natural'Image...``` stuff isn't doing what it's supposed to do. It's converting a string that might look something like ```(.)``` into a number, as you can see in the result:

```./tree 4
( 0.)
(. 0)
( 1.)
(. 1)
( 2.)
(. 2)
( 3.)
(. 3)```

Comment: @zengod that extra space is actually a sign (if numebr was negative it would have been -). Natural is subtype of Integer and for 'Image and 'Value (among other) base type is used (i.e. it is equivalent to Integer (X)'Base'Image in this case).

Comment: @darkestkhan, no, my bad, I have wrong read question - this numbers are index of element in tree while whole question is about recursion - insert previous elements of vector into next element of vector. So, this lines 21 and 22 should be: ```Strings.Append("(" & Tree(N - 1).Element(String_Vectors.To_Index(T)) & ".)");```